# How to deal with missing data? Info will be used for data visualization

Tags: dataframe, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

How does everyone deal with missing values in dataframe? I created a dataframe by using a Census Web Api to get the data. The 'GTCBSA' variable provides the City information which is required for me to use it for (plotly and dash) and I found that there is a lot of missing values in the data. Do I just leave it blank and continue with my data visualization? The following is my variable

Example data for 2004 = https://api.census.gov/data/2004/cps/basic/jun?get=GTCBSA,PEFNTVTY&for=state:*

Variable description = https://api.census.gov/data/2022/cps/basic/jan/variables/GTCBSA.json

[image]

Comment: I think we need a little more information to answer your question. What kind of data visualization are you doing and for what purpose? For example, if you're plotting these points on a map using the city, then it's going to be difficult to fill in the city and you might consider excluding these points.

Comment: @DerekO So I am required to collect information about the ethnic makeup of cities across the US to understand the changing demographics. I have another column that has the ethnic, but I couldn't figure what I should do with these missing cities.

Comment: @DerekO Did I do something wrong during this process btw? Since the data is collected from the government, I thought they wouldn't be any missing data. However, I am quite new to this and it's the first data project I am working on so I totally have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of [dealing with missing data](https://www.mastersindatascience.org/learning/how-to-deal-with-missing-data/) depending on the use case and the type of data that is missing. For example, for a near-continuous stream of timeseries signals data with some missing values, you can attempt to fill the missing values based on nearby values by performing some type of interpolation (linear interpolation, for example).

However, in your case, the missing values are cities and the rows are all independent (each row is a different respondent). As far as I can tell, you don't have any way to reasonably infer the city for the rows where the city is missing so you'll have to drop these rows from consideration.

I am not an expert in the data collection method(s) used by the US census, but from [this source](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/gov-finances/technical-documentation/methodology/how-the-data-are-collected.html#:%7E:text=Data%20for%20the%20balance%20of,used%20were%20incomplete%20or%20questionable.), it seems like there are multiple methods used so I can see how it might be possible that the city of the respondent isn't known (the online tool might not be able to obtain the city of the respondent, or perhaps the respondent declined to state their city). Missing data is a very common issue.

However, before dropping all of rows with missing cities, you might do a brief check to see if there is any pattern (e.g. are the rows with missing cities predominantly from one state, for example?). If you are doing any state-level analysis, you could keep the rows with missing cities.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, I appreciate it. What you said does make sense, I will drop the row with missing cities. However, I was not able to drop the rows with "0" value though when I tried to drop the row. I started another thread to ask for help. Would you mind looking at it if it's something you know what to do? Thank you.

Comment: @dspassion i'm glad my explanation was helpful – and it looks like your follow up question was answered. thanks for accepting my answer!